# Pygame - when i push a button and then another

Tags: python, pygame

First of all, here is my code:

```
while not crashed:
    curr_event = pygame.event.get()
    if (len(curr_event) == 2):
            print curr_event[0],'\n',curr_event[1],'\n\n\n'

    for event in curr_event:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and not len(curr_event) == 1:
            continue
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            x_change = 0
    x += x_change
    Display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)
```

This should be a try to move smoothly from right to left and opposite.
All is good when for example, I press "left key" and wait 2 seconds and then press "right key".
But - when I press "left key", leave the key, and just after it press "right key" - the "key up" is smashing my right press and the player stops on the screen.

I thought it's because created a list of 2 indexes when the first have the "right press" and the second have the "key up", so i tried to do:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and not len(curr_event) == 1:
            continue
```

As you can see in my code.
Well... sometimes it's the situation... But sometimes it doesn't creates a list with two indexes - but smash the "right key" pressing..

How can I fix it and what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the mouse, pressing buttons and other actions counts as events and are put in the queue, so the code `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and not len(curr_event) == 1: continue` might be unreliable.

### Solution

You could check the state of the button (if it's being held down or not) rather than just when it's pressed and released. `pygame.key.get_pressed()` returns a list of all the keys current state: 0 if not being pressed and 1 if it's being pressed. A key position in the list is it's integer constant representation.

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x_change = -5
elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    x_change = 5
```

This doesn't keep track on was what pressed first or last, so if you're holding down both keys it'll go left. I've tried another solution that works pretty well. It basically a list that keeps track of the key presses in a list and moves the player based on the last key pressed.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x, y = 100, 100
car = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
velocity_dx = []
speed = 5
while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                velocity_dx.insert(0, -speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                velocity_dx.insert(0, speed)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                velocity_dx.remove(-speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                velocity_dx.remove(speed)

    try:
        x += velocity_dx[0]  # Take the first value from the list
    except IndexError:  # if list is empty, catch the IndexError.
        pass
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(car, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()

    # print(velocity_dx)  # Uncomment to see what's happening in action!
```